# Find hundreds of records among millions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb table that contains currently 11 millions of records.

```
    {
            "_id": "5a0dc8528b7f1f00102b5006",
            "timestamp": "2017-08-25T03:49:37.000Z",
            "value": 150,  
            "isVerified": 0
    }
```

I want to fetch all the records where `isVerified` is equal to `0` (few hundreds) :

```
db.getCollection('record').find({"isVerified" : 0})
```

The problem is that the query takes 12 seconds to end and my database will increase significantly in the future.

How can I accelerate the process ?

Comment: I fear your options are live with it, dive into the source code of Mongo and see if you can do better than their devs at writing a search algorithm, or use a different database tool. EDIT: Or you can just create an index, apparently :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an index :

```
db.getCollection('record').createIndex({"isVerified" : 1})
```

More info : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/